# Best way to structure MySQL database that holds submissions from multiple forms?

Tags: mysql, database, forms, database-design

I need to set up a database that will contain submissions from forms in multiple locations. Each form will have the same exact fields, the only difference being the page it lives on.

Would it be best for me to create a table for each location? Or should I have 1 table for all submissions and put the location in as a field in that one table?

Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you'll be better off with one table for all submissions.

If *location* means "web page", you probably ought to store something more relevant. Data like "my_hot_web_page" is less relevant, "mobile.fahrven.com/pay_rent_now" is better, "Pay rent" is probably best.  (Unless the web page itself is more important than what it represents.)